# "Could not write file" error in wp_upload_bits function

Tags: uploads, attachments

I'm trying to scrape images from the web and upload the binary files by using `wp_upload_bits` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_bits)

This works fine for about 95% of the images, but some images can't be uploaded. I'm getting the following error: `Could not write file %s`.

The full code for this error in the function is:

```
$ifp = @ fopen( $new_file, 'wb' );
if ( ! $ifp )
     return array( 'error' => sprintf( __( 'Could not write file %s' ), $new_file ) );
```

I've been debugging this function and everything looks fine (the filename etc).

Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: You should remove the `@` operator, it takes any warnings and errors that happen and silences them, it's a debugging nightmare and can hide quite catastrophic errors. Also can you show the code that calls `wp_upload_bits`? Was there any particular reason not to use the more fully featured/easier `media_handle_upload`?

Comment: Hi Tom, I removed the @ operator. Getting the following error: 
`Warning: fopen(/var/www/admin-acceptatie.test.nl/releases/20161219133135/web/app/uploads/2016/12/informatiecentrum-amsterdam-door-atelier-kempe-thill-3.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin-acceptatie.test.nl/releases/20161219133135/web/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2150`

Comment: I will have a look at `media_handle_upload`. Can this function upload binary data? Because i need to upload the binary data to wp_uploads folder before i can call `wp_insert_attachment`.

Comment: See [the codex for details](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload), and check your filesystem to see that it's possible to write to that location from PHP

Comment: Hi Tom, I dont think the problem has to do with the permissions, because 95% of the images upload correctly into the folder. Is it possible to upload binary date with `media_handle_upload`?

Comment: I don't know, but there's no reason why it shouldn't, and permissions is definately a problem, the error message explicitly says it failed because `Permission denied`. Just because your other files uploaded doesn't mean the entire uploads folder has the apprpriate permissions, perhaps only parts of it have the right permissions and you're only just running into the issue now?